# Javascript is strange on math operations

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I have this simple [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w7rdg35e/1/) code. And I am confused why I get these results:

for 21 I get 2

for 23 I get 1,999999999998

for 25 I get 2

for 28 I get 1,999999999998

for 18 I get 1

for 38 I get 3

What's up with 23 and 28 ?

Code:

```
var x = prompt(x);
x = x/10 - x%10 / 10;
alert(x);
```

Comment: Obligatory: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: It works: `x = ( x - x%10 ) / 10;`

Comment: Yea I know but I wanted to know why that way does not work. Because it should. But seems like here is an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken